# Eclipse can't find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, path, ide

Ahhhhhh! I was messing with Eclipse trying to run C programs and after giving up along the way I screwed up everyone of my Java projects.The error message states [image]

So, after alot of research and searching around, it looked like I needed to add my classpath and project files back into the build path, which I did [image]

Please tell me I didn't just ruin everyone of my Java projects. Any help would be so much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The `.classpath` and `.project` files are neither JARs nor class folders as that tab mentions (leave the JRE there, but maybe change the selected `Execution Environment` to a more correct one).

You need to make sure your `src` folder is listed in the **Source** tab, and not the project itself. Otherwise the actual `.class` file won't be created and found by the Java runtime.